# Set custom data- attributes on {{#linkTo}} helper <a> tag

Tags: ember.js, custom-data-attribute

How can I set custom `data-` attribute on the `{{#linkTo}}` helper? I want use this:

```
{{#linkTo "foo" data-toggle="dropdown"}}foo{{/linkTo}}
```

and the result should look like this:

```
<a id="ember323" class="ember-view active"  data-toggle="dropdown" href="#/foo/123">foo</a>
```

but it looks like:

```
<a id="ember323" class="ember-view active"  href="#/foo/123">foo</a>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A way you could do this is to extend your `Ember.LinkComponent` to be aware of the new attribute:

```
Ember.LinkComponent.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle']
});
```

And then you can use it in your `{{#link-to}}` helper:

```
{{#link-to 'foo' data-toggle="dropdown"}}Foo{{/link-to}}
```

This will result in:

```
<a id="ember262" class="ember-view active" href="#/foo" data-toggle="dropdown">Foo</a>
```

And since `attributeBindings` is an array your can put multiple attributes there that you might need:

```
attributeBindings: ['data-toggle', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: where do you put this code? I'm using ember-cli and haven't learned yet where a file like this should go. Also, is {{#linkTo}} a custom helper you made, or did you mean to write {{#link-to}}?

Comment: @redOctober13 Thanks, I corrected my answer `link-to` is now the new helper and is included out of the box. As for ember-cli it picks up files by file name, so a view should live in the `views` directory.

Comment: Updated to from `LinkView` to `LinkComponent`. As pointed out in an other answer, in Ember 2.0+ views have been deprecated. Use `Ember.LinkComponent.reopen` instead.

Answer (score 9):

@intuitivepixel

Thanks

U helped a lot. With that Information I've played arround with the LinkView and was able to find a generic solution:

```
Em.LinkView.reopen({
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        var self = this;
        Em.keys(this).forEach(function(key) {
            if (key.substr(0, 5) === 'data-') {
                self.get('attributeBindings').pushObject(key);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution has been more or less added to the official documentation: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/#toc_adding-data-attributes

Comment: Weird. I wonder why data attributes are blacklisted by default.

Comment: In Ember 2.0+ Views have been deprecated. Use `Ember.LinkComponent.reopen` instead.

Comment: it would be a good idea to check programmatically which version of Ember is being used, like checking if `Ember.LinkView` is undefined and then using `Ember.LinkComponent` instead. this would make it backwards-compatible with Ember 1.x