# Defining an ID for html element in Emberjs/handlebars fails

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, handlebars.js, dalekjs

I have following issue here:

```
<ul class="aClass">
  {{#if something}}
  <li>{{#link-to "blub" bind-attr data-testid=aID}}{{loc "blub"}}{{/link-to}}</li>
  {{/if}}
</ul>
```

so i want to have an element(the link-to is rendered to `<a href="">...</a>`) in the resulting element with the id **aId**. But the element does not contain the wanted id in the rendered HTML. something like this:

`<a href="" data-testid="aID">...</a>`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ember, `bind-attr` shouldn't be used inside of your `link-to` help as that should only be used inside of html elements:

```
<a {{bind-attr href=myLink}}>My Link</a>
```

Inside of Handlebars helpers, you just define the property directly.

```
{{#link-to "blub" data-testID="aID"}}{{loc "blub"}}{{/link-to}}
```

The attribute is not rendered into the HTML if the quotes are missing.

But you also need to reopen the `LinkView`:

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
    attributeBindings: ['data-testID']
});
```

[See similar question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400147/set-custom-data-attributes-on-linkto-helper-a-tag)

[And the Ember docs here.](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/)

Comment: Hey, you made my day :) But i had to add the quotes to get it working properly --> @sheldonnbbaker thank you too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using quotes:

`{{#link-to "blub" bind-attr data-testid="aID"}}{{loc "blub"}}{{/link-to}}`

A lack of quotes will cause Ember to try a property lookup on the current view context, instead of just spitting out a string as you'd like it to.